# Finding the position of a value in PostgreSQL arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql, position

How can I get the position of a value in PostgreSQL arrays?  There's [`.index()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method for Python and [`array_search()`](http://kr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) function for PHP, but I cannot find any such function for PostgreSQL. Should I write a stored function to do that? I prefer to solve by using a built-in function.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Since version 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html), there is built in functions: `array_position()` and `array_positions()`, for searching array key(only first occurrence) or keys(all occurrences), by value.

These functions supports anyarray type.

Answer (score 31):

The [documentation recommends](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING) using the `generate_subscripts` function.  The function below emulate's PHP's `array_search`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION array_search(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY)
RETURNS INT AS $$
    SELECT i
      FROM generate_subscripts($2, 1) AS i
     WHERE $2[i] = $1
  ORDER BY i
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

This returns the index of the first match, if present.  If you want all matches, simply change `RETURNS INT` to `RETURNS SETOF INT`.  This function, as is, returns `NULL` if no match is found.

This function only works with one-dimensional arrays.

Also, bear in mind that `array_search(NULL, a)` always returns `NULL`, even if the array contains null elements:

```
> SELECT array_search(null, array[1, 2, null, 4]);
 array_search 
--------------

(1 row)
```

This is because SQL considers `NULL = NULL` to be *unknown* (i.e. `NULL`).  See [functions-comparison](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html).  If you want `array_search` to be able to find `NULL` elements, change

```
     WHERE $2[i] = $1
```

to

```
     WHERE $2[i] IS NOT DISTINCT FROM $1
```

Comment: Nice answer. This will get simpler and more efficient when PostgreSQL 9.4 adds `WITH ORDINAL` functions, allowing you to just write `unnest(the_array) WITH ORDINAL`. Maybe I should write and submit a proper `idx` function for 9.4, though...

Answer (score 6):

For integer arrays *only* you can use the greatly faster [`idx` function from the `intarray` bundled extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html).

This function hasn't been generalized to support all array types yet, unfortunately, so you're stuck with a very slow SQL approach for other arrays.