# Order by a particular value or array of values of an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

It is possible in Active Record (Postgres) to order objects by a particular value or array of values of an attribute?

Lets say I first want to show the contents with certain tag, then continue with a similar tag, the continue with contents with no tag. This is intend to use on a page with infinite scrolling, so it makes sense to show first the most relevant content and then the less relevant content as he scrolls down.

`Order` does work by giving an attribute and DESC or ASC, but what If I want to sort them by a set of values of a particular attribute instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to say something like:

> "Sort items on the `blah` column with values in the following order: `('fred', 'bob', 'joe', [others], NULL)`"

If so, that's not natively possible in SQL. It's possible ActiveRecord adds something on top, but I'm not sure how you'd express it.

In PostgreSQL you'd probably write this as an `ORDER BY ... CASE`, something like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN the_col = 'fred' THEN 1
  WHEN the_col = 'bob' THEN 2
  WHEN the_col = 'joe' THEN 3
  WHEN the_col IS NOT NULL THEN 99999
END;
```

(`NULL` sorts after any value in the default `ASC` order unless you specify `NULLS FIRST`, and `CASE` produces `NULL` if nothing matches).

See [this simple demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/994a0/6).

Performance will get *dramatically* worse as the list grows. This is something you can use for a few values, preferably not tens, and certainly not hundreds. Also, standard SQL doesn't require databases to support expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause, so this may not be particularly portable. Expressing it in ActiveRecord is up to you.

If PostgreSQL offered an `idx(element, array)` function for arbitrary arrays like the `idx` provided for integer arrays in the `intarray` module then you could simplify this a bit, but ... it doesn't. So you need a full length `CASE`.

You can, however, wrap it up in an SQL or PL/PgSQL function that takes an array argument. This might let you call it from AR, though it's likely to make the effiency situation even worse given that it does two inefficient array sort-and-scan operations for each tuple:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0885d/1

```
-- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798055
CREATE FUNCTION array_search(needle ANYELEMENT, haystack ANYARRAY)
RETURNS INT AS '
    SELECT i
      FROM generate_subscripts($2, 1) AS i
     WHERE $2[i] = $1
  ORDER BY i'
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION case_sort(e anyelement, a anyarray)
RETURNS integer
AS '
SELECT CASE
  -- Yes, this wastes time searching the array twice.
  -- You could use PL/PgSQL to avoid that, but it would
  -- probably be slower over-all.
  WHEN array_search(e, a) IS NOT NULL THEN array_search(e,a)
  -- maxint
  WHEN e IS NOT NULL then 2147483647
END;'
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;

SELECT *
FROM order_demo
ORDER BY case_sort(sortcol, ARRAY['fred','joe','bob']);
```

Alternately, as suggested by Mu in the comments, you could see if ActiveRecord can cope with a variadic function more easily than an array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION case_sort(e anyelement, VARIADIC a anyarray)
RETURNS integer
AS '/* function body unchanged from above */'
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;

SELECT *
FROM order_demo
ORDER BY case_sort(sortcol, 'fred', 'joe','bob');
```

per updated demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/84ed8/1

Comment: Expressing it in AR will probably be a bunch of string wrangling in Ruby. You can hand `order` a string to use as the ORDER BY expression.

Comment: @muistooshort Fun. Well, that's what one gets for using ActiveRecord I guess. Though surely the updated approach using a function over an array would work (if not be pretty *or* fast)? Tell me you can at least use function calls as generic expressions in AR and pass arrays as parameters...

Comment: I'm not sure it will know what to do with an array, Rails4's PostgreSQL driver has some understanding of arrays but I'm not sure how far it goes. A variadic PostgreSQL function might be easier to work with but I don't have much experience with those. In truth, I find AR to be very difficult to work with but that's probably because I have a stronger database background than most of the people involved with and using AR.

Comment: @muistooshort variadics are very easy; `somefunc(a text, VARIADIC b text[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::text[])` looks and behaves to the contained function body exactly like it was declared `somefunc(a text, b text[])` and called with an array argument.