# Without using for loop how to check whether an element of an array starts with particular string in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In my postgresql query im using a for loop to check whether an element of an array starts with particular string. If it starts with that particular string then my query will display the index of that element.

Eg :

```
FOR  i in 1..array_length(array[childrens],2) LOOP  -- childrens is the array
    IF position('SP' in childrens[i]) != 0 THEN
  ......
```

In this loop im checking element by element which is time consuming. So please can anyone suggest me some idea to do this task and reduce the time taken.

Comment: some test data would be nice

Comment: I think you can use the same solution for this problem as I have shown in my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18764095/330315 instead of using `= 1` in the outer query, you could use a `LIKE '%SP%'`

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option here is to use unnest.  It's too bad we can't use any(array) like 'sp%'  On well....

```
  WITH  array_search AS (
        select id, unnest(childrens) item 
          from mytable
         where item like 'SP%';
  )
  SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id in (select id from array_search);
```